# How can I call the action of a checkbox button when the cell is touched?

Tags: swift, uitableview, checkbox

I'm using a custom cell which contains a label and a button. In my button, i've an action associated with it i.e when the button is touched the button changes its image and changed to checked image. But i want that action to be call when entire cell is touched.

```
extension HostOptionViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Question.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let question = Question[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestionOptionCell") as! ViewCellTableViewCell
        cell.setText(option: question)
        arrayOfCells.append(cell)
        return cell
    }
```

In my Custom cell

```
import UIKit

class ViewCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var DataCell: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkBox: UIButton!

    @IBAction func CheckBoxFunc(_ sender: Any) {
        if checkBox.isSelected{
            checkBox.isSelected = false
        }
        else{
            checkBox.isSelected = true
        }
    }

    func setText(option: Data){
        DataCell.text = option.data
    }
}
```

I want to call "CheckBoxFunc" when the cell is touched.

[image: Action for the button.]

Comment: You are not making much sense.  Why would you need a checkbox as an instance of UIButton, then?

Comment: So if the checkBox is selected i want the data of that particular label in an array. Also it it difficult for the user to tap on a particular area of the cell to select the checkbox, thats why whenever the user taps on the cell, i want to call the action "CheckBoxFunc"

Answer (score 0):

If you want the **CheckBoxFunc** to be called when selecting cell, then you should call it in **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Get your Custom cell here using dequeueReusableCell
    // Call the CheckBoxFunc
}
```

Comment: The function “CheckBoxFunc” is in a different file where I’ve defined my custom cell. And all my table methods are in a view controller. So I tried this thing but it crashed the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedCell: ViewCellTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as! ViewCellTableViewCell
    selectedCell.checkBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TableViewController.checkBoxTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func checkBoxTapped(sender:UIButton) {
    let question = Question[sender.tag]
    print(question)
}
```

> Don’t forget to add tag for checkbox button in `cellForRowIndex` method .